# Add the values in the rule

Tags: rule

```
{
 a -> 1,
 a -> 2,
 b -> 3,
 b -> 4
 }
```

You can see that both a and b have two values, so how do I add these two vaule?Like this

```
{a->3,b->7}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Merge[Total]@{a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3, b -> 4}`

Comment: Or preface with `Normal@` to convert to rules.

Answer (score 6):

Another suggested solution is suggested below.

The logic is to transform the list of rules into a list of lists, sort it and then sum over.

With

```
lst = {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3, b -> 4};
```

we do

```
Rule @@@ ({#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ 
   GatherBy[Sort[List @@@ lst], First])
```

having borrowed from [**`Syed`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278154/sum-of-the-second-elements-in-the-list-of-pairs/278155#278155)

The above returns

> [image: res]

Answer (score 5):

Just another way to do this using `GroupBy`:

```
Map[Part[#, 1] -> Total@Part[#, 2, All, 2] &, Normal@GroupBy[lst, Keys]]
(*{a -> 3, b -> 7}*)
```

Or in a compact way using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
Normal@GroupBy[lst, Keys,Total@#[[All, 2]] &]
(*{a -> 3, b -> 7}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Reap[MapApply[Sow[#2,#1]&]@rules,_,#1->Total@#2&][[2]]

(* {a -> 3, b -> 7} *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
Reap[Sow[Last@#,First@#]&/@rules,_,#1->Total[#2]&][[2]]
```